# C++ : how to get address of current function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

here is my problem:

I have a function pointer vector and an iterator for it:

```
std::vector<void* (*) (void*)> f_callbackVector;
std::vector<void* (*) (void*)>::iterator f_callbackVectorIterator = f_callbackVector.begin();
```

I populate the vector with some functions:

```
f_callbackVector.push_back((void* (*) (void*))handleDeliveryModeChange);
```

When I am in the function, I want to be able to check that the iterator holds a pointer to this current function. I tried this:

```
void handleDeliveryModeChange(SESSION s, const DELIVERY_MODE d1, const DELIVERY_MODE d2) {
    if (static_cast<void (*) (void*, DELIVERY_MODE, DELIVERY_MODE)>((*f_callbackVectorIterator)) == &handleDeliveryModeChange) {
    LOG_MESSAGE("\n\n\n\nWOW\n\n\n\n");
}
}
```

and got:

```
invalid static_cast from type âvoid* (*)(void*)â to type âvoid (*)(void*, DELIVERY_MODE, DELIVERY_MODE)â
```

I would appreciate some help with this.

Thanks!

**UPD:**
I tried:

```
if (*(f_callbackVectorIterator) == &handleDeliveryModeChange)
```

and got error: `comparison between distinct pointer types âvoid ()(void)â and âvoid ()(void, DELIVERY_MODE, DELIVERY_MODE)â lacks a cast`

I even tried this monster:

```
if ((*f_callbackVectorIterator) == static_cast<&(void* (*) (void*))>(&handleDeliveryModeChange))
```

Still no luck, got lots of obscure syntaxis errors.

Answer (score 4):

`&myfunc` gets the address of the function.

Comment: I tried using if ((*f_callbackVectorIterator) == &handleDeliveryModeChange) and got error: comparison between distinct pointer types âvoid* (*)(void*)â and âvoid (*)(void*, DELIVERY_MODE, DELIVERY_MODE)â lacks a cast

Comment: not sure where the star before f_callbackVectorIterator disappeared in my comment. It is there in my code.

Comment: because your function signatures don't match.

Answer (score 1):

You are lying to the compiler:

```
f_callbackVector.push_back((void* (*) (void*))handleDeliveryModeChange);
```

`handleDeliveryModeChange` does not match this signature.  Its signature is actually:

```
void (*)(SESSION, DELIVERY_MODE, DELIVERY_MODE)
```

You could make it work by changing to this: [Code](http://ideone.com/rBw3kV)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef void* SESSION;       // Or whatever it is
typedef void* DELIVERY_MODE; // You didn't say what these are
typedef void* (*Func) (SESSION, DELIVERY_MODE, DELIVERY_MODE);
typedef std::vector<Func> FuncVector;

FuncVector f_callbackVector;
FuncVector::iterator f_callbackVectorIterator = f_callbackVector.begin();

// Note: Your pointers return void*, so I changed the return type from void:
void* handleDeliveryModeChange
(
  SESSION s,
  const DELIVERY_MODE d1,
  const DELIVERY_MODE d2
)
{
  if ((*f_callbackVectorIterator) == &handleDeliveryModeChange)
  {
    std::cout << "\n\n\n\nWOW\n\n\n\n";
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{

  f_callbackVector.push_back(handleDeliveryModeChange);
}
```